# How check if value exists in request POST?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I submit form using POST method. Form has one input field: `time`.

I tried to check if exist parameter:

```
if 'time' in request.data:
   pass
```

But it does not work

Comment: Where are you submitting your form from? How are you receiving it? Where are you attempting to obtain the submitted data? So many questions...

Comment: I use Flask: `@app.route('/schedule/<int:adv_id>', methods=['POST'])
def schedule(adv_id):`

Comment: The code that will handle your arguments can read in the time key by using either `request.data.get('time')` or `request.data['time']`.

By calling `request.data.get('time')`, the application will continue to run if the language key doesn’t exist in the URL. In that case, the result of the method will be `None`. 
So you need
```t = request.data.get('time')
if t:
pass
```
Source: [digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/processing-incoming-request-data-in-flask)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use `request.form` if you're posting your data as a regular POST body query, i.e.:

```
@app.route('/schedule/<int:adv_id>', methods=['POST'])
def schedule(adv_id):
    if "time" in request.form:
        pass  # do whatever you want with it
```

Comment: Thank you, how to check if value not null?

Comment: Not null, or not posted at all? A general concept would be: `if request.form.get("time", None): ...`